# A half-wave rectified sinusoidal waveform has a peak voltage of 10V. What are its average value and the peak value of the fundamental component?

Tags: fourier

I know to to find average value: 10/pi

What does "peak value of fundamental component" mean?

Comment: Average is not what you said. Peak value of fundamental component is probably the peak to peak value of the original summer wave OR half that depending on the mindset if the question setter

Comment: Welcome to the forum! Can you be more focus on the problem? What are you trying to achieve? Where did you find the phrase "fundemental component" -and what is the "fundemental component"? Also, could you edit the question, by makint a smaller title and post the first question (that you have o the title) on the body?

Comment: A rectified sinus wave is composed of "harmonics" ... (of course, it is not a sinusoid). So it has an average DC component value, and "some" harmonic content. https://cnx.org/contents/mdjhtFcx@11/Fourier-Series-Example or this https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-1-349-20994-1%2F1.pdf

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios this site IS NOT a forum.

Comment: You're asking for definitions. I'm sure you can find them in your textbook. They'll be near the section that tells you how to calculate them.